# Side-by-side Markdown edit compare on Meta is unreadable

Tags: bug, design, meta

[image: Screenshot of the side-by-side markdown revision page]

On the revisions page for a post here on the Meta site, if you select the 'side-by-side markdown' option to see the markdown of the changes, you get extremely low-contrast text for the changed areas, as the above shows.

<sub>Generated on Firefox 19.0</sub>

Edit by Izkata:  This is still a problem.  Firefox 29:

[image: Firefox 29 screenshot]

Comment: For once, the "Questions that may already have your answer" was actually useful.  This was the first question listed

Answer (score 2):

[The redesign (not yet launched)](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7581/a-design-update-is-coming) will fix that

> [image]
>
> [image]